# How can I add multiple metrics in a pie chart using Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have 4 column:

1. Company name
2. Work done
3. Work to be done
4. Revenue

Columns 2, 3 and 4 (`Work done`, `Work to be done` and `Revenue`) are currency expressed in Eur format.

I need to represent this data in a [pie chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7187587) as 3 different slices (column 2, 3 and 4).

Comment: What's the data set (Google Sheets, Google Analytics, Big Query, SQL based, etc)? One approach would be to transform the data at the data set, though it would require a minimal reproducible example, such as a publicly shared Google Sheet or a Google Data Studio Report...

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you could replicate the scenario on a fresh Google Data Studio Report using sample data that would also be proof that it is a reproducible issue! if you could then share that Google Data Studio Report publicly and add a link in the question, it would allow fellow users to test it out. Without a Reproducible Example it would be **difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration, Temporary Outage**...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert `Work done`, `Work to be done` and `Revenue` to categorical values in a single column, e.g. something like this:

| Company name | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Work done | €100.00 |
| a | Work to be done | €200.00 |
| a | Revenue | €400.00 |
| b | Work done | €200.00 |
| b | Work to be done | €200.00 |
| b | Revenue | €400.00 |

[This GDS dashboard](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/897d48fe-d807-4d0a-bdbb-5919bcb71470) generates a pie chart using a Google Sheet datasource with these columns and rows. The pie chart dimension is `Type` and the metric is `Amount`. Make a copy of the dashboard to see the chart configuration.